# Word wrap in split text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to animate text in paragraph in my site by letters.
I split my text and wrap each letter in `<span>`, so I built structure like this with jQuery:

```
<p>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>O</span>
</p>
```

For using css transforms I added property `inline-block` for spans.
Now animation works fine but I have problem with word wrapping.
Text wrap after each letter not only on space.

I tried to use `word-wrap` and `white-space` but it doesn't work :/
What can I do ?

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wm9sxb49/1/)**

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle to have a better view of this please ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes, here you have simple example of my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/wm9sxb49/1/

Comment: `word-wrap` and `white-space` won't work as the `span` tags won't provide information where should a "word" break (i.e. location of a space). Pure CSS probably can't work, if you don't change the structure; you'll need JS to scan the space & apply line break.

Comment: I worked out a semi solution ( [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/wm9sxb49/5/) ). Try to resize the HTML canvas to view the result

Comment: It works fine, but I think it's a bit inefficient bacause it require updates on window resize :( I found another solution, but in my case I have messy semantics :/ Please look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/wm9sxb49/7/

Answer (score 0):

It works good with `float:left;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/wm9sxb49/2/)

```
p{
  font-size: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span{
  float: left;
}
```

Just saw that on an answer on SO :

> inline-blocks are like characters, which means spaces are counted in
>   the width too. Remove spaces/new lines between divs to get what you
>   what. Or switch to other layout method, like float: left.

[CSS margins: Why does this layout behave this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541954/css-margins-why-does-this-layout-behave-this-way)

Comment: Spacing is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "letter-spacing" css to p tag to increase or decrease the space.