# CSS margins: Why does this layout behave this way?

Tags: html, css

I try to teach myself some CSS currently.

I have made this example-layout:

```css
.group div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="group">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The div-elements within are all 100px width plus 10px margin-left and 10px margin-right. Sums up to 120px. 4 times 120px makes 480px.

=> It should fit into the wrap-element which has a width of 500px.

But it doesn't. The fourth element breaks into a new line. I have to increase the width to 510 for to fit it into one line.

**Why?**

Even with firebug I couldn't find a reason ...

Comment: Does it break into a new line? Not for me, not the output of the snippet.

Comment: I see all of them in 1 line

Comment: Could you share what browser are you using? because seems to render ok in some.

Comment: @LionelT Sure. Firefox 45.0.1

Comment: I suspect your font size is different from the default font-size. If your font-size is bigger (say more than 26px) then it will wrap around because there is always a white space between two inline block elements (unless you leave no space in the HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block`s are like characters, which means spaces are counted in the width too. Remove spaces/new lines between `div`s to get what you what. Or switch to other layout method, like `float: left`.

Answer (score 2):

change `display-inline` to `float`

```css
.group div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="group">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to understand `display: inline-block;` default behavior when you use `inline-block  <div>`  automatically take some space from left and right to avoid that space you need to use `letter-spacing: -4px;  and font-size: 0;` then you will have right result see snippet

```css
.group div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="group">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

onther option change your HTML

```css
.group div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="group">
    <div>1</div><!--
--><div>2</div><!--
--><div>3</div><!--
--><div>4</div><!--
--></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you transform some `block element` to `inline` or similar (`inline-block`) you make it sensible to typography rules (whitespaces, line-height, and something else).

A easy and fast solution for your problem is to remove whitespaces from your dom (like follows).

this article is a good resource: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

```css
.group div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="group"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div></div>
</div>
```